# Installation pandas failed due to a deprecated API

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I wanted to trythe famous python's library pandas so I tried to install it with the command bellow:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

But that lead to a failure which said that my Python.h file was missing then I did:

```
 sudo apt-get  update
 sudo apt-get install  python-dev -y
```

I used pip install once again but I got another error (I add a screenshot) and I can't find out how to fix it.
Do you know what is this error and how to fix it?[image]

Comment: *apt-get install g++* might help i.e. you are missing a C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot it solve my problem can you do a post I will validate it to close the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error given gcc

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

indicated that C++ compiler package was not installed. In case of debian and ubuntu, this can be done by

```
apt-get install g++
```